# Can't access index of a list for maximum value with argmax

Tags: arrays, list, numpy, argmax

I am working on a Naïve Bayes Classifier and I got this list of arrays as the log predictions:

```
predict = [array([-45.73329593, -47.23015876]), array([-56.83024746, -59.20630121]), array([-53.17297542, -55.19852072]), array([-35.67031864, -36.09391906]), array([-65.57891295, -66.81787995]), array([-62.64077968, -64.78048969]), array([-60.44866178, -61.96371683]), array([-46.36333681, -49.33896595]), array([-44.94102615, -46.89321275]), array([-58.67657099, -60.2740146 ]), array([-62.4623459 , -64.55626115])]
```

I have been trying to run: `np.argmax(predict, axis = 1)` in order to pick the maximum value of `predict`. I use `argmax` to return the corresponding index but it keeps throwing this error: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. Why is it throwing that error?

Comment: If `predict` is a list, why are you doing : `predict(X_test)`?

Comment: My bad! I'm trying to use `argmax` in `predict`. Sorry for the confusion. Gonna edit the question.

Comment: `np.argmax(predict, axis = 1)` works fine for me on given sample data with edited code.

Answer (score 0):

predict is a `list` not a `numpy array`

try to put the list into a numpy array

```
>>> predict
[array([-45.73329593, -47.23015876]), array([-56.83024746, -59.20630121]), array([-53.17297542, -55.19852072]), array([-35.67031864, -36.09391906]), array([-65.57891295, -66.81787995]), array([-62.64077968, -64.78048969]), array([-60.44866178, -61.96371683]), array([-46.36333681, -49.33896595]), array([-44.94102615, -46.89321275]), array([-58.67657099, -60.2740146 ]), array([-62.4623459 , -64.55626115])]
>>> type(predict)
<class 'list'>
>>> pred_a = np.array(predict)
>>> type(pred_a)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```